# How can I enable/disable an asp.net form/controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

How can I enable/disable an asp.net form/controls selectively or entirely from code-behind?

The following code is not working. Coz there is no Enabled property in this case.

```
public static void Disable(Page container)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < container.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        container.Form.Controls[i].Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-disable-all-controls-in-ASP-NET-page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the controls that inherit from [WebControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.aspx) will have a `Enabled` property. So you could do something like this inside your loop:

```
var webControl = container.Form.Controls[i] as WebControl;
if(webControl != null) {
    webControl.Enabled=false;
}
```

Comment: Documentation says Enabled false will "dim" the controls and make them not editable at the client side. It's closer to what JMSA wants but documentation says it's only functional in browsers compatible with "Internet Explorer 4+". WTF is a browser compatible with IE4?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be browser safe though

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`Visible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible(VS.71).aspx) instead of `Enabled`. The ASP.NET framework will not call the Render method of controls for which the Visible property is set to false.

From the documentation:

> If this property is false, the server control is not rendered. You should take this into account when organizing the layout of your page.